# React Native Camera - How?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I followed the steps at https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md

to install a camera for my ios app, and successfully downloaded the necessary libraries to use the camera. Now I'm confused on how to implement it within my app. I have looked around on GitHub, docs, and tried a couple of videos, but just can't figure out what I should do next. I'm not sure how to use the camera on my app/get it to show up, I've just downloaded its libraries.

What I have so far:
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';

```
<RNCamera  ref={cam => {this.camera = cam}}  style={styles.preview}  
aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>  
<Text style={styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>  
[CAPTURE]  
</Text>
  </RNCamera>
```

Should this go in a separate class? It doesn't do anything to my output. I've learned the basics of Javascript/ReactJS, now I'm trying to put it all together.

Comment: Add some code you have done by now would be helpful

Comment: @keikai - I have simply imported the camera: import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';       and I'm assuming I need some sort of component that uses this camera library right?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your recommendation, I added a bit more info

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be as simple as importing Camera from the package and using it as `<Camera />`! There are some permissions to set up, first, though (recognize: "Would you like to allow app "Some App" to access your Camera?)

There's a code example here, permissions are first but the Usage section shows you the React code:

https://www.google.com/amp/s/reactnativeexample.com/a-camera-component-for-react-native/amp/

I'm sorry, though, this doesn't look like the same npm package that you've installed already. You could replace it, or just use this demo as a guideline, they're very likely to be almost identical.